# ERC-721 not found on testnets.opensea.io for Polygon Mumbai?

Tags: nft, opensea

I've published two test ERC-721 contracts to the Polygon Mumbai test net.

Both of them work as expected when the view functions are called directly on PolygonScan and support the same interfaces.

But only one of them will show up on OpenSea when I search from them in the search bar @ testnets.opensea.io.  Both contracts actually point to the same metadata url, so I don't think its the metadata.

Is there any way to diagnose this problem?

The api's aren't much help.  When I try to use
`https://testnets-api.opensea.io/assets/0xB9e9ce9B79E2402577f591DadC8Dc2250d5dD2E4/1`

it just returns `{"success": false}` even though that's the contract that shows up when you type it in the search bar. (Same result for the one that doesn't)

I am under the impression you don't need an api key for the testnets-api but maybe that's the problem.  Apparently there its hard to get the api key.  You apply and then just wait . .

Any thoughts on why a contract wouldnt appear would be helpful.

Thanks.

---

Answer (score 1):

Try :
`https://testnets-api.opensea.io/asset/mumbai/0xB9e9ce9B79E2402577f591DadC8Dc2250d5dD2E4/1/validate/`

You can find all information about debugging metadatas [here](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/4-debugging-your-metadata).